# How to programmatically Autowire a bean based on Qualifier Annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-junit, junit5-extension-model

In Junit5, when using Extensions, we can run BeforeAll and AfterAll methods, and I'm trying to change behaviour of the test using Annotations.
However, I'm using these annotations as @Qualifiers as well for bean initialisation, and want to be able to initialise a bean using the Annotation identified on the test

I wish to programmatically Initialise the Bean on run time using my Qualifier Annotations
I know `SpringExtension` for Junit5 can get

```
SpringExtension.getApplicationContext(context).getAutowireCapableBeanFactory()
```

Using which I can call the bean initialisation factory, but I don't know how to initialise the beans using Annotations which are Qualifiers
I have multiple Beans of same type, identified by Qualifiers

**The problem I'm stuck with is**

Currently, I'm statically initialising the Type of user credentials using AutoWired and then basis the annotation I'm using the pre-initialized UserCredential using switch case.

The idea is to have a test class `@ExtendsWith(ResetPortal.class)` and then it indicates, which type of user it can use to Reset (Login before test) with.
I'm using Qualifier Annotations to indicate that, which I can then extract from `ExtensionContext` from the Junit5 `beforeAll` methods

Further, I have a `UserCredential` class being and multiple @Bean definitions for that class for each type of user.

**Code**

Bean definition, using custom qualifier annotation User1Qualifier

```
@Bean
  @User1Qualifier
  public static UserCredentials clientBankLogin(
      @Value(LOGIN_USERNAME_1) String username,
      @Value(LOGIN_PASSWORD_1) String password) {
    return new UserCredentials(username, password);
  }
```

With my Custom qualifier being as below (there are multiple)

```
@Qualifier
@CustomValueAnnotation("User1")
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({FIELD, PARAMETER, TYPE, METHOD})
public @interface User1Qualifier {}
```

Now, in the tests, I'm trying to use the same Annotation, which the ResetPortal picks up

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith({ResetPortal.class, SpringExtension.class})
final class LoginTest extends SpringTestBase {

      @Test
      @User1Qualifier
      void clientLogin() {}
}
```

The ResetPortal class, since Junit5 initialises the class and calls it's managed instance, needs Autowired elements to be defined separately

```
@Service
public class ResetPortal implements BeforeEachCallback, AfterEachCallback {

     static UserCredentials user1;
     static UserCredentials user2;

     Autowired
     public void initializeLoginToPortal(@User1Qualifier UserCredentials u1, 
                                         @User2Qualifier UserCredentials u2) {
                 user1 = u1;
                 user2 = u2;
    }

    @Override
      public void beforeEach(ExtensionContext context) {

      // This is the custom Value annotation marked on each UserQualifier
      // This is using AnnotationUtils#findAnnotation(java.lang.Class<?>, java.lang.Class<A>)
      CustomValueAnnotation loginAs = getLoginAsAnnotation(context);

      switch (loginAs){
       case "User1" : loginWith(ResetPortal.user1); break;
       case "User2" : loginWith(ResetPortal.user2); break;
      }
    }
}
```